# Oracle reports output like HTML table from single database cell

Tags: oracle11g, report, oraclereports

Is it possible to create HTML-like table in Oracle Reports (output format: .rdf) based on database cell content ?
Report is big, with lot of content, from which one should be formatted cell content.
What is currently:
[current data displayed in ready report - database cell content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF4KK.png)
What is requested:
[what should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3y4H.png)
Using HTML formatting in this case doesn't work,
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/bi.1111/b32122/orbr_concepts2008.htm#RSBDR481
HTML tags are very limited for an .rdf report.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality, using another technique?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Wizard to create a report (you should have; it does a lot of *dirty* job for you), it also creates layout and puts everything into its place, creating a "grid" (table), something very close to what you need.

Navigate to paper layout editor where you can choose to format lines (cells, frames) - in the vertical toolbar, pick a line color (for example, black). In (horizontal) menu, go to Format menu (and then Line and Border submenus), selecting borders you want (top, bottom, right, left).

Once you're done, run the report and you should see a pretty table.

---

Saying that "output format is .rdf", that's *wrong*. Report is *saved* as a .rdf file, but its output can be, for example, a PDF file.

Never mind that, it was just a side note.